# Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History'. Function could not be cloned

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, axios, react-router-component

On the following very basic project:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-history-push-with-function-as-arg?file=src%2Fpages%2FPage1.jsx

I have the following code:

```
import React from "react";

class Page1 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      letter: 'A',
    };
  }

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.history.push({
      pathname: '/page2',
      state: {
        myFunction: () => {
          console.log('Cancelling Axios Request!');
        },
      }
    });
    return false;
  };

  render() {
    return <>
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <div>You are currently on: Page 1 (Letter: {this.state.letter})</div>
        <br />
        <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button><br />
      </form>
    </>;
  }
}

export default Page1;
```

**My problem is that** I need to pass a function to the `Page2` through the call to: `this.props.history.push({...})`. For that I'm using: `myFunction` inside the `state` array (which is normally used to send parameters on the transition).

**Side note you can skip:** in my real scenario will be a function that will take care of cancelling an `Axios` call, especifically with: `axios.canceltoken.source().cancel()`. Reference: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/all-need-to-know-about-axios),

but when transitioning to `Page2` I get the following error:

```
Error: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': () => {
console.log('hello world');
} could not be cloned.
```

as you can see here:

[image]

I know I could save the function on the `window` object while on `Page1` and use it while on `Page2` but I think that's not a good practice. As I said above, my end goal is to be able on `Page2` to cancel an `Axios` request I started on `Page1`.

Is there a way for me to pass that function to `Page2`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't pass a function but you can pass an ID and function parameters. The same way we (used to?) do with Redux.

Comment: is there a way to cancel an Axios request by having an id or something that can be propagated to other component via props?

Comment: No, AFAIK (you need to store the token in your own global record or map). However you might ask yourself if, in this case, you need to: requests started in Page1 could (should?) be canceled there, in componentWillUnmount().